# Clustering days based on features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, k-means

I am trying to perform a inner-clustering of a time-serie constisting of days (i.e, clustering similar days) using a set of features $x_i = [f_1, f_2, ..., f_n], i \in D$ set of days. I can choose between two different set of features, $x_{1_i}$ in which the generic $f_k$ is a categorical feature, and $n=600$, or $x_{2_i}$ in which $f_k$ is instead a numeric feature but $n=10$.

I have to cluster days based on the previous features (preferably a method for each set of features, which should not be used together but whose results may be merged). However, such method should yield a division which respects a sort of "temporal soft-constraint".

Suppose in fact that the number of cluster $h = 5$. Suppose now that the vector yielding the cluster for the day from $i \in [0, 10]$ is $$[1,1,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,4]$$
Although it successfully clusterizes the days, it yields a division which shows little adjacency (we only have a "big" adjacent cluster from index $i=0$ to $2$). Instead, a vector like: $$[1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3]$$
Provides a better adjacency.

The final scope of my clustering should be to identify approximate trends which last more than a single day, even though they do not maximizes a similarity between days. Nevertheless, it should not be random but it should also take into consideration similar days.

I know the problem is a bit hard. I've tried to introduce, alongside my feature vectors, a temporal-feature (insert the day index, normalized, in the vectors) and performed a k-means clustering. In order to account for dimensional difference between my new index and the other features number, I have tuned a weight $w$ which should multiply my temporal index and maximizes a custom definition of the adjacency.

Namely, I defined the measure of adjacency as the total number of adjacent cluster number divided the count of adjacency is interrupted. For example, in my first example, the total count is $2$ and, counting the numbers, I am interrupted by a dissimilar cluster (v[3] = 2 \neq v[2] = 1) just once. So $adj = 2/1 = 1$. In the second case, we have $adj = 6/3 = 2$. However, I do not know if such measure is good enough in my case. I didn't observe improvements in my tuning approach (namely, $w=1$ yields the best result).

To complete my question, I will provide an example of feature vectors. $$x_{0_1} = [0, 0, -1, 1, ..., 0]$$
so $f_k \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$. Instead: $$x_{0_2} = [301.2, -100.10, ..., 0.234]$$
so $f_k \in R$.